# Why won't this class library raise events when compiled as DLL?

Tags: c#, events, class

I've got a project that I'm using an example off codeproject that allows you to burn CDs and DVDs from C#. Included is a working ZIP of the code:
http://workorderlive.com/codeproj/Burn_Test_NoDLL.zip

When I isolate the CS files for a class library (so I can import it into a VB Proj I'm doing) I can get the class library to burn just fine, but events arn't being raised. I've included a copy of the original project, but the CS files replaced with a compiled DLL:
http://workorderlive.com/codeproj/Burn_DLL_Events_test.zip

The events work in the first example, but not the second. I'm afraid I'm not sure why.

Here's the code i'm using for the class library:
workorderlive(dot)com/codeproj/Burn_DLL.zip

Comment: So, here's the line that fixed it to expose events properly: `[Guid("2735413C-7F64-5B0F-8F00-5D77AFBE261E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]`

Specifically adding InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's the line that fixed it to expose events properly:

`[Guid("2735413C-7F64-5B0F-8F00-5D77AFBE261E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]`

Specifically adding InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)